# Copy range instead of cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Progress_speichern()

    Const SRC_NAME As String = "C1 EV Application"
    Const SRC_DATE_CELL As String = "C2"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "C0 EV (Historie)"
    Const DST_DATES_LEFT_CELL As String = "S2"
    Const DST_KPI_ROW As Long = 3

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim sDate As Date: sDate = sws.Range(SRC_DATE_CELL).value
    Dim srg As Variant: srg = wb.Sheets("C1 EV Application").Range("AD5:AD25").value

    
    Dim drrg As Range
    
    With dws.Range(DST_DATES_LEFT_CELL)
        Dim LastCol As Long:
        'find last column and define range to be used
        LastCol = dws.Cells(.Row, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last cell to the right in this row
        Set drrg = .Resize(, LastCol - .Column + 1)
    End With

    
    Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(CLng(sDate), drrg, 0)
    
    ' Checks if there are values in the cell beneath the desired month. If yes, it asks the user, whether he wants to rewrite the old value, otherwise the sub is exited
    If drrg.Cells(cIndex).EntireColumn.Cells(DST_KPI_ROW).value <> "" Then

        If MsgBox("Für diesen Monat gibt es bereits alte Werte. Wollen Sie diese überschreiben?", _
        vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Alte Werte gefunden") Then GoTo Case1 Else GoTo Case2
Case1:
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) = True Then
                        drrg(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW).value = srg '
                        ' drrg.Cells(cIndex).EntireColumn.Cells(DST_KPI_ROW).value = srg
                End If
Case2:
                Exit Sub
                
    Else
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) = True Then
                drrg(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW).value = srg  
        End If
    End If
    

End Sub
```

I have two sheets. On Sheet1 (C0 EV (Historie)) Data is entered. A user chooses a date and presses a button. A range from sheet 1 is copied to sheet 2. Then from this range of data a KPI value is calculated. Previously only the KPI value was copied, now I want to copy a whole range, where the kpi value sits beneath the range. The KPI value is included in the range(AD5:AD25) (AD5-AD22 are values, 2 empty rows, then the KPI). The data is always matched to  a date. There dates are fixed dates (listed monthly from cell S2 on horizontally) on sheet 2. Now application.match looks where the matching date is and tries to paste the range beneath the respective date.

```
drrg.Cells(cIndex).EntireColumn.Cells(DST_KPI_ROW).value = srg
```

This works, it copies the a single KPI value. Now i basically want to copy a range instead of onyl a cell.

```
drrg(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW).value = srg
```

But the arguments for row and column don't seem to work as I want (only one value is copied and on the wrong place).

```
Set drrg = .Resize(, LastCol - .Column + 1)
Set drrg = .Resize(20, LastCol - .Column + 1) 'Resize the Cell to a size of 20 -> AD5:AD25 -> 21 rows
```

Here I tried to resize the drrg, I thought maybe I'm not copying to a wide enough range but this didn't work, too.

Comment: Set your range to the cells you want to give a new value, give the other range the values you want to give to first range and then it's just a simple `drrg.Value = srrg.Value`. `drrg(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW)` is used to specify a specific cell in the built range drrg. You could also specify it different: `drrg(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW).Resize(yourNeededRows, yourNeededColumns).Value = srrg.Resize(yourNeededRows,yourNeededColumns).Value` (yourNeededColumns can be left out).

Comment: Isn't that exactly this? I mentioned that already. I tried:

`Dim srg As Variant: srg = wb.Sheets("C1 EV Application").Range("AD5:AD25").value`

and 

`drrg(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW).value = srg`

But only the top value was copied. Am I dumb or did I missread your answer?

I tried the resizing, too, didn't I?

`Dim srg As Variant: srg = wb.Sheets("C1 EV Application").Range("AD5:AD25").value`

Comment: `(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW)` causes it to be one cell in the drrg range hence you getting the singular value. If you'd be copy pasting, you could have a singular cell as the destination range and still paste all the values from the source range but since you're using `.Value`, it's a little different. The issue of resizing is with your destination range, i.e. `drrg`. Try `drrg(cIndex, DST_KPI_ROW).Resize(UBound(srg,1),UBound(srg,2)).Value = srg` since srg is an array.